# iPhone : How do I update my project from iOS 3.0 to iOS 4.3 (or iOS 5.0) which includes MessageWebLayer?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, messageui

I have to update project from iOS 3.2 to iOS 4.3 (or iOS 5.0).

I found that in iOS 3.2, they have used `MessageWebLayer.h` private file of framework.

But [from this link](http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=/System/Library/Frameworks#), I found that its public from iOS 4.3.

When I try to implement `MessageWebLayer.h` in my app it gives me error.

And from my search I found that i have to use MFMailComposer of `MessageUI` framework.

Code which works fine with iOS 3.2

.h file

> ## import "MessageWebLayer.h"
>
> MessageWebLayer *message;

.m file

> CGRect webViewFrame = CGRectMake(0, 118, 768, 4000);
>
> message =[[MessageWebLayer alloc] initWithFrame:webViewFrame
>   visibleSize:webViewFrame.size];

If i try to run this in iOS 4.3 it gives me error like

`_OBJC_CLASS_$_MessageWebLayer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MessageUIAppDelegate.o`

But still I am unable to solve problem ?

What should I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I have solved my problem.

In `iOS 3.0`,

`MessageUI.framework` contains private header file that is `MessageWebLayer.h`.

And in `iOS 4.3` and `iOS 5.0`,

`MessageUI.framework` contains private header file which is now renamed as `MFMessageWebLayer.h`

So, I have replaced `MessageWeblayer.h` file with `MFMessageWebLayer.h` file.

And also changed object and related method to this private header file.

So its working fine and giving proper outputs. :)

---

Q. :  How to get this private header files from `MessageUI.framework` ?

Ans :

1 )  Download [class-dump-z](http://code.google.com/p/networkpx/downloads/list)

2 ) And then use the last option from the [this link](http://code.google.com/p/networkpx/wiki/class_dump_z)

Answer (score 0):

Add `MessageUI.framework` to your project & update your xCode to latest version to compile app for later iOS like iOS 4.3 or 5.0.

Comment: i have already tried that but If i do so, It gives me error for MessageWebLayer.h

Comment: Can you post your error? Where do you get your MessageUI.framework from? I suppose you include it inside xCode, but not download from the Internet.

Comment: I have downloaded It. and also included in my project. Its working fine with iOS 3.2. but Not working in iOS 4.3 and iOS 5.0.

Comment: My point is: **DO NOT DOWNLOAD IT**. The latest version is included in xCode already. Just import it to the project like your other frameworks. Also, please post more codes.

Comment: I tried your way but still having trouble. And check my updated question

Comment: In case you didn't aware, using undocumented headers are forbidden in App Store approval process. what are you going to achieve?

Comment: I have app requirement which is going to run only on simulator. And MessageWebLayer (Private framework) was used before the iOS 4.3 and from iOS 4.3 its public but I dont know how to use ? as its giving me error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to download this [private framework](https://github.com/kennytm/iphone-private-frameworks). Replace the MessageUI Framework and try that. Try to find out latest updated MessageUI Framework. Hope that could work

**EDIT:**

After refering to some of the below links :

https://www.elance.com/p/blog/2011/10/ios5-a-developers-perspective.html

http://gravityjack.com/gravityjack_news/ios-5-for-developers-what-you-need-to-know.html

http://blog.vanitypoint.com/2011/10/key-improvements-developers-are-eyeing-on-ios-5/

I have encountered that in iOS 5 there has been a significant changes in `MessageUI framework`  So try to extract only MessageUI framework from iOS 5 SDK and use that framework in your app.

Comment: I did not find any useful information from your links. And that private frameworks are for the old iOS3.2. you better take look at my question and then try.

Comment: And one more thing there is no different in MessageUI.framework which is in iOS 4.2 and iOS 5.0. but there is great difference in iOS 3.2 and in (iOS 4.2/5.0). you can see this by extracting MessageUI.framework.